# Are all data types in JavaScript enumerable?

Tags: javascript, enumerate

I know that object properties has 3 flags and with one of them I can set a certain property non-enumerable. But in all other cases are all types of data enumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- By default all properties created **using simple assignment** or via
  a **property initializer** are **enumerable** irrespective of data
  type.
- Properties defined via methods like `Object.defineProperty,  Object.defineProperties` are by default **non enumerable**.

Ex:

1.Property Initilaizer (by default enumerable):

```
const obj = { a: 'foo', b: 123, c: {} };
```

2.Simple assignment (by default enumerable):

```
obj.a = 'foo'
obj.b = 123
obj.c = {}
```

3.Object's methods (by default non-enumerable):

```
obj = {};  
Object.defineProperties(obj, 
    {   a: {   value: 'foo' },
    {   b: {   value: 123 },
    {   c: {   value: {} }
);
```

Further reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).